# Component - Subcomponent Relationship or Generalization Relationship? in Component Diagram UML

Tags: uml, associations, generalization, component-diagram

I'm under confuse with the Component - Subcomponent relationship and 
Generalization relationship between the components.

When do we need to mention two components as Component - Subcomponent relationship and when to mention them as Generalization relationship.

Can the Generalization relationship (Figure A) be mentioned as the Component - Subcomponent relationship (Figure B) within in Component Diagrams in all the time? (It is understandable that inverse is false)

***Figure A :***

[image]

***Figure B :***

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The notation in figure `B` is used to represent [component realization](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html#component-realization) relationship.

  > [www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF/):
  >
  > **11.6.3 Structured Classifiers → Components → Semantics**
  >
  > ...A `Component` may be realized (or implemented) by a number of Classifiers. In that case, a `Component` owns a set of `ComponentRealizations` to these `Classifiers`.
  >
  > A component acts like a `Package` for all model elements that are involved in or related to its definition, which should be either owned or imported explicitly. Typically the `Classifiers` that realize a `Component` are owned by it...
- You can use the [generalization](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html) relationship (figure `A`) between components as usual because component is an [UML classifier](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/classifier.html) like any other class.

But figure `A` and figure `B` represent **different things** and figure **`B`** in your example is **not ok**

Comment: The 2nd figure shows a nesting (sub-components) while the first shows a generalization. So ONE of both is wrong.

Comment: @ThomasKilian guessing from the names in OP's example you will not use "Car" and "Hotel" and "Air Conditioning" to implement(realize) a "Service Controller" component and deliver it to the client. They seem to be distinct things, used at different times in different pieces of software at different places. So figure `B` is wrong. They may share some behavior and even code so they may be connected by the generalization relationship, so figure `A` is what OP wanted to express

Comment: Hi xmojmr, Thank you for  the answer and the valuable information. So, that means, generally, if  component is "owned" by another then we can say there's a component realization relationship between them. Isn't it?

Comment: @Namalak I read the definition this way too. But from the UML metamodel perspective a component can package ("own") another without really needing/using it so there would be no realization. Also `UML Superstructure 2.4.1` says: "_..It should be noted that for the purpose of applications that require multiple different sets of realizations for a single component specification, a set of standard stereotypes are defined in the UML Standard Profile. In particular,
«specification» and «realization» are defined there for this purpose.._". If you need to call things _right_, consult the specification